# Segmentation fault when executing binary in runc container

Tags: segmentation-fault, containers, linux-capabilities, runc

I'm having a particular issue with a *runc* container. I have a bash script (running as root) that's executing the following:

```
$ setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep ${PACKAGE_DIR}/bin/my-binary
$ chpst -u vcap:vcap "${PACKAGE_DIR}/bin/my-binary" --config "${JOB_DIR}/config/config.json"
```

every time, when it runs at container start it fails with this output:

```
 5116 Segmentation fault      chpst -u vcap:vcap "${PACKAGE_DIR}/bin/my-binary" --config "${JOB_DIR}/config/config.json"
```

However:

- When I ssh or shell into the container and run the command by hand,
  it will work.
- If I remove the `chpst -u vcap:vcap` (run as root) it    will also
  work.
- If I remove the `setcap cap_net_bind_servic...` declaration, it will
  also work.
- When I change chown `my-binary` to `vcap:vcap`, it will work.

But none of these are valid options for the real implementation. I've even edited the source code of the binary to simply sleep for 2 hours - which had no effect, so I don't think the actual source code of the binary is the cause. Is there something I'm missing?

My runc version is:

```
runc version 1.0.0-rc5+dev
commit: 69663f0bd4b60df09991c08812a60108003fa340
spec: 1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing piece of the puzzle was these bit of logs here:

```
[  197.027144] bosh-dns[29239] vsyscall attempted with vsyscall=none ip:ffffffffff600000 cs:33 sp:7ffeeb9ea458 ax:ffffffffff600000 si:0 di:7ffeeb9ea460
[  197.028504] bosh-dns[29239]: segfault at ffffffffff600000 ip ffffffffff600000 sp 00007ffeeb9ea458 error 15
[  197.028772] bosh-dns[29233] vsyscall attempted with vsyscall=none ip:ffffffffff600000 cs:33 sp:7ffea26a3028 ax:ffffffffff600000 si:0 di:7ffea26a3030
[  197.028774] bosh-dns[29233]: segfault at ffffffffff600000 ip ffffffffff600000 sp 00007ffea26a3028 error 15
```

I don't know why but the fix for my problem was to add `vsyscall=emulate` to the kernel command line arguments that I was using.